# LINQ method to count how many students have at least one greatest grade in subject

Tags: c#, linq

We have list of students and grades. **Students** have `ID, Surname, Name, ProgrammeID`, while the **grades** class: `StudentID, SubjectCode, Date and Value`.

The main idea is to find all students that have at least one greatest grade (`Grade class -> Value >= 10`) in all subject that he attends to.

I should mention that all of this information (Student and Grade) are stored in separated List.

Student and Grade class looks like this:

```
class Student
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProgrammeID { get; set; }

    public Student(string id, string surname, string name, string programmeID)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Surname = surname;
        this.Name = name;
        this.ProgrammeID = programmeID;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join("; ", ID, Surname, Name, ProgrammeID);
    }
}

class Grade
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string SubjectCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Grade(string studentID, string subjectCode, DateTime date, int value)
    {
        this.StudentID = studentID;
        this.SubjectCode = subjectCode;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join("; ", StudentID, SubjectCode, Date, Value);
    }
}
```

Example:
We have three attendees and three marks: (Only `Student` that has code - `B13798` should be displayed, because the `Student` that has code - `B13799`, has value of 10 in only one of the provided two subjects)

```
atendees.Add(new Student("B13799", "Surname0", "Name0", "P175B123"));
atendees.Add(new Student("B13799", "Surname0", "Name0", "P175B122"));
atendees.Add(new Student("B13798", "Surname1", "Name1", "P175B123"));

marks.Add(new Grade("B13799", "P175B123", DateTime.Parse("2021-01-02 12:45:36"), 10));
marks.Add(new Grade("B13799", "P175B122", DateTime.Parse("2021-01-02 12:45:36"), 9));
marks.Add(new Grade("B13798", "P175B123", DateTime.Parse("2021-01-02 12:45:36"), 10));
```

Comment: Not sure I understand but maybe `students.Where(s => grades.Any(g => g.StudentId == s.ID && g.Value == 10)).ToList()`?

Comment: Updated the text with in depth explanation. Your provided code (unfortunately) not giving the right result :/

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine , i think he want student that have all grade greater than 10 :  `students.Where(s => grades.All(g => g.StudentId == s.ID && g.Value >= 10)).ToList()`

Comment: @Mantofka You're saying that only `B13798` has a full mark in one of the subjects but `B13799` does too. What am I missing?

Comment: Look at the mark initialization, there are two marks that corresponds with the same student id. However, these two marks have different subject ids (so one subject has grade of 10, but another is not, hence it shouldnt appear on the result list)

Comment: But didn't you say _"find all students that have **at least one** greatest grade"_? If you want to find students who got full mark in _all_ subjects, maybe you're looking for `atendees.Where(s => marks.Where(g => g.StudentID == s.ID).All(g => g.Value == 10)).ToList()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not giving right results (tried with different testing data) The problem is that you are not reading whole paragraph. "Find all students that have at least one greatest grade (10) in all subjects that he attends to"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First group the marks to find the highest mark for each student and subject

```
var group1 = (from r in marks group r by new { r.StudentID, r.SubjectCode } into results 
select new { results.Key.StudentID, results.Key.SubjectCode, max = results.Max(x => x.Value)});
```

Then group these results by student

```
var group2 = (from r in group1 group r by r.StudentID into results select results);
```

Finally select just those students who have a 10 for every subject

```
var list = (from r in group2 where r.All(a=>a.max == 10) select r.Key).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

- create one group of marks *per student* by grouping `marks` by `StudentId`
- for each such group (`marksForStudent`), create one group of marks *per subject* by grouping `marksForStudent` by `SubjectCode`
- for each student, verify whether each such group (`marksForSubject`) contains at least one mark that passes your given requirement
- filter which students are of interest based on this verification
- select the `StudentId` of the students of interest

It may be implemented like this:

```csharp
List<Student> attendees;
List<Grade> marks;

// Populate lists

var threshold = 10;

var filteredAttendeeIds = marks
    .GroupBy(mark => mark.StudentID)
    .Where(marksForStudent => marksForStudent
        .GroupBy(mark => mark.SubjectCode)
        .All(marksForSubject => marksForSubject
            .Any(mark => mark.Value >= threshold)))
    .Select(marksForStudent => marksForStudent.Key);
```

The students can then be found by intersecting the filtered student IDs by the student list:

```csharp
var filteredAttendees = attendees
    .IntersectBy(filteredAttendeeIds, attendee => attendee.ID);
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9dqle).

Note: This implementation assumes that for each `Student.ProgrammeID` in `attendees`, there is in fact an existing `Grade` object in `marks`.

---

**Side note:**
I would recommend replacing the `Student`'s `string ProgrammeID` property with `IEnumerable<string> ProgrammeIds`, and collect all the student's programme IDs there. That way, you can define each student once, rather than defining the same student for each and every programme they attend.